# Spring annotations: Is there a similar annotation like @ExceptionHandler used in Controller stereotypes for @Repository or @Service stereotypes?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I tried to see if I could use [`org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/) in a Repository out of curiosity.  As expected the annotation is ignored.

I have a low priority instrumentation service that I don't want exceptions to bubble up from.  Rather than coding each method on the instrumentation service with a try/catch I would have liked to have a `@ExceptionHandler` method for the service - similar to technicques used in a Spring `@Controller`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you can get this from Spring right now (perhaps you want to make a feature request...), but you should be able to do this pretty easily with [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).

```
@Aspect
public class DaoAspect {
    @AfterThrowing(/*any method in a @Repository class that is not annotated with @ExceptionHandler*/ throwing="ex")
    public void doRecoveryActions(DataAccessException ex) {
        //find method of throwing class that can handle the exception via @ExceptionHandler
    }
}
```